# Unchecked cast warning when return generic implementation based on Class<> argument

Tags: java, generics

I have the following setup:

```
@Override
public <T> Optional<EndpointProvider<T>> getProvider(Class<T>   providedClass) {
    if(providedClass.isAssignableFrom(RecommendationCategory.class)){
        return Optional.of((EndpointProvider<T>) new RecommendationCategoryProvider());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

private class RecommendationCategoryProvider implements EndpointProvider<RecommendationCategory> {
```

And the compiler is giving me an unchecked cast warning. I would think that checking providedClass.isAssignableFrom(RecommendationCategory.class) would prevent a unchecked cast warning.

Is there any way to not have this warning in this setup?

Comment: Sometimes, the compiler will throw a warning in which you just know better. In a perfect world it wouldn't but it's nothing to lose your head (or development time) over.

However in this case, I believe you would need to be sure you're checking the component type, vs the base class. if you're already doing that then great, you're smarter than the compiler in this case.

Comment: You can use [@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) to tell the compiler to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I could come up to do it.  It won't show any warnings.

```
public static <T> EndpointProvider<T> getProvider(Class<T> klass)
{
    if (klass.isAssignableFrom(RecommendationCategory.class))
    {
        return new EndpointWrapper<T>(klass.cast(new RecommendationCategory()));
    }

    return null;
}

private static class EndpointWrapper<X> implements EndpointProvider<X>
{
    public EndpointWrapper(X wrapper)
    {

    }
}

private static class RecommendationCategory
{

}

private static interface EndpointProvider<T>
{

}
```

Comment: Please note i would need to cast it to EndpointProvider<RecommendationCategory> and not RecommendationCategory it self. So i can not do this.

Comment: Edited the answer - There is no way to safely check generics at runtime.

Comment: Hi thanks for editing, but it's still not applicable for this case. I need to check the isAssignableFrom because when it's not assignable from i need to return Optional.empty. And in the production code there are a bunch more if else statements for providers for other classes.

Comment: @bob It might be useful to just use `instanceof` as it can be optimized more easily by Java.

Comment: But wont providedClass always just be an instance of Class and not the type i want? Or can i use it in a different way in this case?

Comment: @BobBrinks I updated the answer with the only way I could figure out how to do it.